# how to fix "Element.alignToXY with an element that doesn't exist" javascript error

Tags: javascript, ext.net, gridpanel

On `ext.net` grid panel mouse hover I am getting this error:

```
Exception thrown not caught
```

While debugging this line:

```
throw "Element.alignToXY with an element that doesn't exist";
```

Comment: Please provide a test case to reproduce.

Comment: Thanks Daniil, I have fixed the issue with CSS